# Visual Basic web browser open links in default browser

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a small application and i have a web browser that loads a certain url when it is opened.  The problem if you click a link inside that visual basic browser it opens the URL in internet explorer.

Is there a way to set it so all links that are opened in the VB browser open in default and not IE?

EDIT: I have added my code below to you can get a better idea

```
    Public Class UpdaterBrowser
    Private Sub UpdaterBrowser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
        WebBrowser.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
        WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.co.uk/")
    End Sub
End Class
```

EDIT Again:

Google is not the website being used, i have changed it. But the website is set to open links in new tabs/windows on all links.

Comment: This is unusual behavior... The WebBrowser control does *not* open links in an external browser. You've obviously written code to do something different. You'll need to [edit] it into your question.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code, it seems the website opens all links on a tab/window. I just need to find out how to force it to do it in default browser out of the vb browser control.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. That was a detail you neglected to mention, that the page you're browsing forces all links open in a new window. That's horrible behavior, discouraged by every known style guide. But if you have to work around it, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312580/366904). Method 2 is probably your winner. Alternatively, you can adapt [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1383888/366904).

Comment: Is there visual basic versions of those code examples? Some of the functions in there arent on VB.net 11

Comment: convert code to vb with http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to prevent the browser from using Internet Explorer.
You should change the default browser in the settings .

P.S. : try to install another web browser on your pc ( for example Chrome or Firefox ) .